# Probability keeping reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory

In the context of $\mathsf{\#P}$ and $\mathsf{PP}$, we have $\mathsf{\#P}$-complete problems, for example $\mathsf{\#SAT}$, however the version that I saw proves this by showing a reduction that keeps the same amount of results but not the same probability. My question is, is it also complete under probability. What I mean by this is this:

Let's define $\mathsf{\%P}$ as the set of functions $f\colon \{0,1\}^*\to[0,1]$ s.t. there is a probabilistic Turing machine $M$ for which for every $x$: $f(x)=Pr[M(x)=1]$.
(Here $[0,1]=\{x\mid 0\le x\le 1\}$.)

Is there a $\mathsf{\%P}$-complete function $g$ in the sense that for every $f \in \mathsf{\%P}$ there is a deterministic polynomial time reduction $R$ s.t. for every $x$, we have $f(x)=g(R(x))$?

Comment: Have you tried constructing such a complete problem? An obvious candidate would accept as input a probabilistic Turing machine and an input, and would run the Turing machine on the input using random coin tosses.

Comment: Yes, this will work. Are there more "interesting" solutions though? For example, I was thinking maybe %SAT (that is given a CNF, the percentage of all possible assignments that satisfy the CNF), because MAJ-SAT is PP complete I feel it should be too, but I couldn't prove this (The classical proof of SAT NP-completness doesn't work because it keeps the exact number of results, not the percentage, that's why it proves #SAT-completness).

Comment: And by the way, I tried to find the proof for MAJ-SAT completeness, but couldn't find anything online, so if you could point me to something I'd appreciate that.